# What am I doing wrong? IR Emitter with Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: gpio, remote, lirc

[image: Raspberry Pi 2 + IR Emitter]

I would like to control my TV with the Raspberry Pi 2.
Using the following hardware:

- Raspberry Pi 2 with Geany IDE
- [QEE113 IR Emitter](http://www.newark.com/fairchild-semiconductor/qee113/ir-emitter-940nm-1-65mm-side-looking/dp/78K6116)
- BC547 NPN Transistor

You can see my wiring on the diagram above, I've followed [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151219152500/http://mvartan.com/2014/11/25/controlling-your-tv-or-any-ir-device-with-raspberry-pi/) tutorial, but I can't get it to work.
Whenever I try to execute the command (which should turn the volume up on my TV):

```
irsend SEND_ONCE emitter KEY_NEXT
```

It doesn't do anything, so I assume that I have some problems with my circuit.

(Lirc is installed and configured.)

Do you know what can be the issue?

Comment: First thing I would do is find out whether the emitter is working.  Typically you can use the camera on your phone to this.  Try it first with a known working remote control because some cameras anymore filter IR... For instance with an iPhone 6 you must use the forward facing camera to see the light from the emitter, the normal back facing camera filters it.

Comment: Are those resistor values accurate?  10k seems too high as does 200.

Comment: The polarity of the diode in your circuit diagram is actually backwards. I can't say whether your actual wiring is or not.

Comment: Obviously you did not follow the tutorial which uses a PNP transistor as an emitter follower. It is far from clear whether you have your transistor and diode connected correctly.

Comment: Sorry guys, yes I've realized that the legs of the transistor are not signed at all...

@Milliways The only difference between a PNP and a NPN transistor is that in PNP the current flows from the emitter leg to the collector leg, whilst in the NPN it flows from collector leg to the emitter

Comment: @GabeB Unfortunatey NOT. You just can't change components like this. Not that I think the circuit you were copying was a great example of circuit design, but it probably works. (I might add that I am an Electrical Engineer with 45+ years of circuit design experience.)

Comment: @Milliways Can you advise me please how would you change that circuit to have a better design?

Comment: Without knowledge of the characteristics of the IR emitter, or the signal you are planning to use I can't design it. I would suggest you look at "Using an NPN transistor" on http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits. Replace the load with the IR emitter and resistor in series. The value of the resistor should be chosen to give the desired current, allowing for the voltage drop across the diode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Milliways answered my question. Probably my IR Emitter wasn't working, I've replaced it and now it is operational.